# I used this iframe to show this page.But i could not get any result

Tags: html, iframe

```html
<iframe src="http://www.educationboardresults.gov.bd/"></iframe>
```

**i used this `iframe` to show this page.But i could not get any result (Its blank). where is my mistake? **

Comment: Are you hosting the Html on a secured/https website? If so, `unsecured` (http://) iframe are usually blocked by browsers

Comment: My browser says "Firefox detected a potential security threat and did not continue to www.educationboardresults.gov.bd because this website requires a secure connection." Change it to `https`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the link redirects to https, you can only put https iframes inside a https page. Mixing the two has been blocked as a a security issue for a number of years